# Authorization based on URL parameters in JAX-RS / Java EE?

Tags: rest, security, jakarta-ee, authorization, jax-rs

We are working on a web application based on JAX-RS. We have multiple parameterized endpoints that access *resources* by resource ID and query some aspect of them. We restrict access to individual resources only to those users who do have the rights to that particular resource. At the moment we are doing this by programmatically / manually checking for said access at the start of the method. What are the best practices, or even just the possibilities, to do this in a declarative / automated way?

The current endpoints look something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/resource/{resourceId}/getWhatever")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getWhatever(@PathParam("resourceId") String resourceId) throws Exception {
    checkForResourceAccess(resourceId, userName and security and whatever);
    String result = query whatever from resource;
    return result;
}

@GET
@Path("/resource/{resourceId}/getAnotherThing")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getAnotherThing(@PathParam("resourceId") String resourceId) throws Exception {
    checkForResourceAccess(resourceId, userName and security and whatever);
    String result = query another thing from resource;
    return result;
}

[...]
```

So far I was thinking about these solutions:

- A custom JAAS LoginModule. No experience in this, not even sure if it possible.
- An interceptor specifically to check access to resources. However this is not reusable, it is strongly coupled to *resourceId*. Feels like a hack really.
- JAX-RS filters and interceptors to filter requests.
- Separate @Path("resource/{resourceId}") service class for these endpoints. @PathParam("resourceId") field, and some kind of automated check for example in a @PostConstruct method.
- Custom <auth-constraint> if possible at all.

The situation is somewhat complicated by the fact that we use SAML 2.0 for Single Sign On authentication.

So, what would be the best practices, or even possibilities, to fulfill this authorization issue, while also conforming to Java EE specifications as much as possible?

Comment: You need to use an externalized authorization module that uses ABAC or XACML